# Haskell: Prefer pattern-matching or member access?

Tags: haskell, coding-style

Suppose I have a `Vector` datatype defined as follows:

```
data Vector = Vector { x :: Double
                     , y :: Double
                     , z :: Double
                     }
```

Would it be more usual to define functions against it using member access:

```
vecAddA v w
    = Vector (x v + x w)
             (y v + y w)
             (z v + z w)
```

Or using pattern-matching:

```
vecAddB (Vector vx vy vz) (Vector wx wy wz)
    = Vector (vx + wx)
             (vy + wy)
             (vz + wz)
```

(Apologies if I've got any of the terminology incorrect).

Comment: Just for completeness: there's also another form of pattern matching using the record fields: `vecAddA (Vector { x = vx, y = vy, z = vz }) (Vector { x = wx, y = wy, y = wz }) = ...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would normally use pattern matching, especially since you're using all of the constructor's arguments and there aren't a lot of them. Also, In this example it's not an issue, but consider the following:

```
data Foo = A {a :: Int} | B {b :: String}

fun x = a x + 1
```

If you use pattern matching to do work on the Foo type, you're safe; it's not possible to access a member that doesn't exist. If you use accessor functions on the other hand, some operations such as calling `fun (B "hi!")` here will result in a runtime error.

EDIT: while it's of course quite possible to forget to match on some constructor, pattern matching makes it pretty explicit that what happens depends on what constructor is used (you can also tell the compiler to detect and warn you about incomplete patterns) whereas the use of a function hints more that any constructor goes, IMO.

Accessors are best saved for cases when you want to get at just one or a few of the constructor's (potentially many) arguments and you know that it's safe to use them (no risk of using an accessor on the wrong constructor, as in the example.)

Comment: On the flipside, if you have `data Foo = A {f :: Int} | B {f :: Int}` then it would be more succinct to write one line using the `f` function to extract the value for either case (assuming the logic for either case is the same), rather than writing two lines to pattern match both cases.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a good idea for a type like `data SomeData = TextData {length :: Int, text :: String} | BinaryData {length :: Int, blob :: [Word8]}`), where two constructor arguments share both type and purpose.

Comment: @Dan Burton: On the flip-flipside, if using the same logic for both is sensible for a type like that, consider rewriting it as `data FooCase = A | B` and `data Foo = Foo { fooCase :: FooCase , f :: Int }`, which also gives you an easy way to check A vs. B without bothering with the rest.

Answer (score 7):

Another minor "real world" argument: In general, it isn't a good idea to have such short record entry names, as short names like `x` and `y` often end up being used for local variables.

So the "fair" comparison here would be:

```
vecAddA v w 
  = Vector (vecX v + vecX w) (vecY v + vecY w) (vecZ v + vecZ w)
vecAddB (Vector vx vy vz) (Vector wx wy wz) 
  = Vector (vx + wx) (vy + wy) (vz + wz)
```

I think pattern matching wins out in most cases of this type. Some notable exceptions:

- You only need to access (or change!) one or two fields in a larger record
- You want to remain flexible to change the record later, such as add more fields.

Comment: As to the second point, "You want to remain flexible to change the record later, such as add more fields.", this can also be a reason for sticking with (positional) pattern matching, as then you have to go over each pattern match to make to make sure you didn't forget to update your functions w.r.t. handling of the additional fields (for instances, think of manually written `NFData` instances)

Answer (score 4):

This is an aesthetic preference since the two are semantically equivalent. Well, I suppose a in a naive compiler the first one would be slower because of the function calls, but I have a hard time believing that would not be optimized away in real life.

Still, with only three elements in the record, since you're using all three anyway and there is presumably *some* significance to their order, I would use the second one. A second (albeit weaker) argument is that this way you're using the order for both composition and decomposition, rather than a mixture of order and field access.

Comment: Agreed, there's no functional difference between the two, and I'm not (at this stage) worried about performance. I'm more interested in whether a more experienced Haskeller would look at one of these and think "that's an odd way of writing it".

Answer (score 4):

(Alert, may be wrong. I am still a Haskell newbie, but here's my understanding)

One thing that other people have not mentioned is that pattern matching will make the function "strict" in its argument. (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lazy_vs._non-strict)

To choose which pattern to use, the program must reduce the argument to WHNF *before* calling the function, whereas using the record-syntax accessor function would evaluate the argument *inside* the function.

I can't really give any concrete examples (still being a newbie) but this can have performance implications where huge piles of "thunks" can build up in recursive, non-strict functions. (That is to mean, for simple functions like extracting values, there should be no performance difference).

(Concrete examples very much welcome)

In short

```
f (Just x) = x
```

is actually (using `BangPatterns`)

```
f !jx = fromJust jx
```

Edit: The above is *not* a good example of strictness, because both are actually strict from definition (f bottom = bottom), just to illustrate what I meant from the performance side.

Comment: +1 You're right. I even missed this myself on the first read through. I've given a slightly clearer example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As [kizzx2 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913130/haskell-prefer-pattern-matching-or-member-access/6928603#6928603), there is a subtle difference in strictness between `vecAddA` and `vecAddB`

```
vecAddA ⊥ ⊥ = Vector ⊥ ⊥ ⊥
vecAddB ⊥ ⊥ = ⊥
```

To get the same semantics when using pattern matching, one would have to use irrefutable patterns.

```
vecAddB' ~(Vector vx vy vz) ~(Vector wx wy wz)
    = Vector (vx + wx)
             (vy + wy)
             (vz + wz)
```

However, in this case, the fields of `Vector` should probably be strict to begin with for efficiency:

```
data Vector = Vector { x :: !Double
                     , y :: !Double
                     , z :: !Double
                     }
```

With strict fields, `vecAddA` and `vecAddB` are semantically equivalent.

Comment: As you've guessed, they are actually strict in the original code. I omitted that to try to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hackage package vect solves both these problems by allowing matching like f (Vec3 x y z) and indexing like:

```
get1 :: Vec3 -> Float
get1 v = _1 v
```

Look up HasCoordinates class.

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vect/0.4.7/doc/html/Data-Vect-Float-Base.html